# Sort and check if numbers are in consecutive order using Java8

Tags: java, java-8

I am trying to sort a list of longs and validate if the numbers are in consecutive order starting from 1. I want to do everything in java8/streams

```
//sorting first
 List<Long> sortedNums = request.stream().map(Request::getSequence)
                .collect(Collectors.toList()).stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());

//getting first num to see if the seq starting from 1
Optional<Long> first = sortedNums.stream().findFirst();

        if (first.isPresent()) {
            if (first.get() != 1) {
                throw new BadRequestException("Sequence should start from 1");
            }
        }
//checking if the list is in consecutive order
 if(!isConsecutive(sortedNums)) {
            throw new BadRequestException("Sequences should be in consecutive order");
        }
 private boolean isConsecutive(List<Long> list) {
        for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.get(i - 1) + 1 != list.get(i)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I am trying to see if there is more optimal way of doing this with stream combining all the statements into one or two.

Comment: What's the point of checking the order after sorting it?

Comment: `.collect(Collectors.toList()).stream()` is pointless.

Comment: @shmosel I think the OP is checking that the numbers are in succession, not just the order.

Comment: If you're already going to throw if the first element isn't one, don't bother with the optional and just do: `first = sortedNums.stream().findFirst().orElse(-1);`

Comment: Ah, you mean if they're sequential.

Comment: Streams are a good way to abstract the order of iteration through the elements, so I don't think it would be suitable for checking if the numbers in your sequence are consecutive. The traditional for-loop you are already using seems ok to me.

Comment: I assume you are talking about n, n+1,n+2,n+3...n+m where n is 1 sequence?

Comment: Sorry I left my workplace. I am checking if the numbers are on consecutive order starting from 1. Means 1,2,3 is valid but 1,2,4 is not valid

Comment: @MS90 yes you are right

Comment: Great! Take a look at my answer. @arjun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this in different small methods instead of one where you do everything:

```
public static boolean startsWith1(List<Long> list){
    //return list.stream().sorted().findFirst().get() == 1; //see @Holger's comment
    return Collections.min(list) == 1;
}
// The sum of all numbers from 1 to n = n * (n+1) /2; 
// you can use that to check if your list contains all numbers from 1 to n
public static boolean isConsecutive(List<Long> list){
    long n = list.size();
    return list.stream().mapToLong(Long::longValue).distinct().sum() == n * (n+1) /2;
}
public static void doSomething(List<Long> list) throws BadRequestException{
    if(!startsWith1(list)){   
        throw new BadRequestException("Sequence should start from 1 ");
    }
    if(!isConsecutive(list)) {
        throw new BadRequestException("Sequences should be in consecutive order");
    }
    else{
        // do whatever with your list
    }
}
```

Comment: `.sorted().findFirst()` is an inefficient way to get `.min(Comparator.naturalOrder())`… Here, you can do even simpler: `return Collections.min(list) == 1;`

Comment: @Holger Thank you very much for that hint. I just adopted that from OP's code and didn't think about it a lot. Indeed `Collections.min(list)` is more elegant than what i have above. Updated.